# Stop AVCaptureSession when leaving ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturesession, ios-camera

I have ViewController with AVCaptureSession. I can start and stop AVCaptureSession easily :

```
var captureSession: AVCaptureSession?
captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

//start
captureSession?.startRunning() 

//stop
captureSession?.stopRunning()
```

A want to know how can I stop AVCaptureSession when user opens another ViewController.

Comment: In `viewWillDisappear` for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have the viewWillDisappear method handle that for you.

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    captureSession?.stopRunning()
}
```